# Java text game parser problems

Tags: java, text, adventure

This is my first post, and I'm only new to Java, so sorry if it is not up to scratch.

I have been writing a text-based adventure game in Java, and my code has failed me in one place - the parser. There is no error, it just doesnt work. It takes in the input but does nothing about it. It is very simple, and looks something like this:

```
public static void getInput(){
    System.out.print(">>"); //print cue for input
    String i = scan.nextLine(); //get (i)nput
    String[] w = i.split(" "); //split input into (w)ords
    List words = Arrays.asList(w); //change to list format
    test(words);
}
```

The test method just searches the list for certain words using `if(words.contains("<word>"))`.

What is wrong with the code and how can I improve it?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: whats the compiler is saying? or is it a runtime error?please tell us whats exactly happening

Comment: "has failed me in one place" how does it fail?

Comment: there is no error, it just doesnt work. it takes in the input but does nothing about it.

Comment: try debugging the code by using break points

Comment: @sleimanjneidi how? like i said, im new to java

Comment: @SamBrev How you know it does nothing?

Comment: @AchintyaJha I tested with a few System.out.println()'s to print things at certain points, like if it found the word "take", or if it didn't find the word "take". it printed neither

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping the array and using something like this:

```
    String[] word_list = {"This","is","an","Array"}; //An Array in your fault its 'w'
for (int i = 0;i < word_list.length;i++) { //Running trough all Elements 
    System.out.println(word_list[i]);
            if (word_list[i].equalsIgnoreCase("This")) {
        System.out.println("This found!");
    }
    if (word_list[i].equalsIgnoreCase("is")) {
        System.out.println("is found!");
    }
    if (word_list[i].equalsIgnoreCase("an")) {
        System.out.println("an found!");
    }
    if (word_list[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Array")) {
        System.out.println("Array found!");
    }
    if (word_list[i].equalsIgnoreCase("NotExistant")) { //Wont be found
        System.out.println("NotExistant found!"); 
    }
}
```

You will get the following output:

```
This found!
is found!
an found!
Array found!
```

As you can see you needn't convert it to a List at all!

Comment: I like this. I only really want a basic two-word parser, so if I do word_list[0] instead of the for loop and [i] would that work?

Comment: um, i tried it but it didnt work. i think the problem might be in splitting it.

Comment: i put a System.out.println to print out the array of words and it came up with [Ljava.lang.String;@3f84246a help me!

Comment: Try using that to get the word_list: String[] word_list = System.console().readLine().split(" ");

Comment: it comes up with a NullPointerException

Comment: Dont use the eclipse console use the Terminal on Mac OS X and Ubuntu and cmd.exe on Windows

Comment: i dont use eclipse i use netbeans

Comment: that doesnt matter , but to respond to that Ljava.lang.String;@3f84246a thingy: You cant write a array out directly use the i variable in the for loop.You needent use System.console().readLine()

Comment: I added an method to print the elements out

Comment: @SamBrev if it worked , it would be nice to mark it as solution :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

```
public class ReadInput {
    private static void processInput (List <String> words)
    {
        if (words.contains ("foo"))
            System.out.println ("Foo!");
        else if (words.contains ("bar"))
            System.out.println ("Bar!");
    }

    public static void readInput () throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = 
            new BufferedReader (
                new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
        {
            String [] words = line.split (" ");
            processInput (Arrays.asList (words));
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception 
    {
        readInput ();
    }
}
```

Sample session:

```
[in]  hello world
[in]  foo bar
[out] Foo!
[in]  foobar bar foobar
[out] Bar!
```

Comment: @SamBrev `System.in` is just STDIN in Java.  `InputStreamReader` is a `Reader` that reads characters from given `InputStream`.  `Reader` in Java is similar to `InputStream` but reads unicode characters instead of bytes.  `BufferedReader` wraps `InputStreamReader` and adds an ability to read input line by line.  All the rest should be obvious.

Comment: it throws an exception; where do i catch it and how?

Comment: @SamBrev It depends on what exception it throws and where.

Comment: @SamBrev The `throws Exception` clause means that method may throw and exception.  This is very unlikely when reading from STDIN, so don't mind.  Method `main` is called by JVM, so JVM is responsible for handling any exceptions thrown from it.